# Anet A8 mainboard dimensions and hole offsets

Tags: anet-a8

I'm trying to get a clean set of measurements of the Anet A8 mainboard and determine the exact positioning of the holes in both the board and frame.

The frame and the board are cut to accommodate an M3 bolt.

Here are the measurements I have currently:

**Mainboard**

- Overall Width 100 mm
- Overall Height 95 mm

**Frame (main board holes)**

- Lateral (measured with calipers)

  - Hole (3.4 mm) Distance +
  - Inner edge hole to hole (83.07 mm)
  - = ~86.4 mm
- Vertical ~90 mm (not measured 100 % correctly)

I was hoping to just find a PCB layout for this board with the measurements and offsets but have found nothing.

I am attempting to provide a mount adapter frame for a PSU with a 50 mm x 150 mm mounting footprint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you download one of the many casings that are found on Thingiverse that house the Anet electronics board and take measurements from those cases.

I measured it from my own casing I designed a while ago:
Hole distances are 86.3 mm and 91.3 mm (center to center)
[image: Anet Board Dimensions]

Comment: Great idea. Unfortunately, my skills at importing/analyzing STL files in the software I have on hand are rudimentary and limited at best. For reference though, the lateral (long edge) holes are, in fact, 86mm apart.

Comment: I updated my answer to include measurements and added a figure with dimensions.

Comment: thanks for the updated answer and the brilliant drawing!!

Comment: @0scar, what is the size of the hole?

Comment: @user77232 It fits M3 screws, so it is slightly larger.